# Sublime regex, replace different characters with different results

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Is it possible to replace multiple different characters with different replaces inside one regex?

I have to replace the following letters:

```
č -> \v{c}

š -> \v{s}

ž -> \v{z}
```

(and all capital versions)

I know I can find all those letters with: `([\x{010C}\x{010D}\x{017D}\x{0160}\x{0161}\x{017E}])`

but how to replace them?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is by running multiple Find/Replace operations. Select **`Find -> Replace...`**, make sure the Regex button is selected, put `č` in the `Find What:` field, and `\\v{c}` (make sure you have two `\\` back slashes) in the `Replace With:` field. Hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd>, then go on to the next one. Sublime supports Unicode search and replace, so you don't need to replace your characters with their Unicode escape sequence equivalents. The `\\` is required before the `v` character, otherwise Sublime will replace with the vertical tab character, whose escape sequence is `\v`.

Comment: Thats the solution I've been using so far, but its quite annoying. So you think it is not possible to do regex replace?
You have to use \\ only if you have regex option turned on in search and replace. Otherwise it's not necessary.